# PXE net-boot: DHCPD and TFTPD on two machines

Tags: dhcp

here is my scenario:

- DHCPD machine (I cannot edit DHCPD settings)
- Machine 1

  - Boots a Live GNU/Linux and offers net-boot with TFTPD
- Machine 2

  - Tries to net-boot, but ends with PXE-E53 error

If I run DHCPD on Machine 1, everything is fine, 'cos I can setup all I need.
How could I setup a PXE environment without affecting DHCPD Machine settings?
Thanks,
hamen

Answer (score 1):

I think you can as you need a DHCP server to redirect the "call" to the proper TFTP server and thus to the install or OS files you want.

You need a specific DHCP server where *filename "linux-install/pxelinux.0";* is properly defined. Otherwise your Machine 2 will not be able to find the necessary files and thus your PXE boot will fail.

Have a look a this (http://idoitonamac.blogspot.com/2012/03/os-x-lion-as-pxe-server.html). I now it's Mac, but you'll see that I managed to have a PXE server on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where there is already in place a DHCP startegy PXE relies on the services of an extra "proxyDHCP server" that does not assign IP addresses but only provides the PXE parameters (bootstrap file name, and TFTP IP address) to booting stations that identify themself as PXE clients.